# Show one view as a part in another view in mvc5

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

I have 3 different views and their respective controllers and action methods. On respective button clicks I am showing each view so far.

Now the client request is a new view, which contains the 1st view as half of the page and the remaining two views as the tabbed views. By default one of the tabbed view has to be loaded in next half of the page, the other view loads only on demand means on the respective tab click.
Note: Each view is from a service call.
Please give me some examples or references to work with. I am hoping for minimal changes in my code

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create it as partial view and you can load it in Tabbed div or any other div. This way you can have as many views you want on a page. Aslo you can load a view later on some event of that page.  [check this stack.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25077624/1957479)

Comment: I removed the layout from the view(Coverage) which has to be loaded as partial view and made the Controller return statement from return view("Coverage", coverageModel) to return ParialView("Coverage",coverageModel) and in the div tag of the main view I have written code like this @{Html.RenderPartial("Coverage")} but it is giving error like the model item passed to the dictionary is of type policyDetails but this dictionary requires model of type CoverageModel. Can u do any help on this

Answer (score 0):

From what you've described above and the comments you made under *one and free*'s post, it seems that you want to have a main page with several partial views rendered both inside and outside of a tabbed panel. Also, after changing the layout a bit you're having trouble resolving the models for (some of) those partial views.

If you are passing "coverageModel" to the main view, but the partial views required different models from different controllers, you should consider using something like the following (this is an example from Bootstrap, but may be applicable to your case):

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-pane active">
            @{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller1");}
     </div>
     <div id="tab2" class="tab-pane">
            @{ Html.RenderAction("Action", "Controller2");}
    </div>
</div>
```

Again, your tab layout may be quite different from the above example, but the important thing is that **RenderAction will be able to render a partial with a different model.**